# Cannot convert value of type '() -> String?' to specified type 'String'

Tags: swift

I want to use a random name from an array as a name for my animation, but I get this error and I don't know how to solve it.

**This is my array:**

```
let animations = ["sports-loader", "loader", "lottie", "mail", "tick-bounce-1", "tick-bounce-2"]
```

**This is the section where I want to grab a random name from the array:**

```
var name: String = animations.randomElement
```

**And here I want to use the name variable:**

```
animationView.animation = Animation.named(name)
```

**Here is a screenshot of my code:**

[image]

Comment: `randomElement` is a function, you need to execute it by doing `randomElement()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** First of all why are you calling `viewDidLoad()` in your `changeAnimationButtonClicked()` method. That's not how you should use `viewDidLoad()`. Its a *lifecycle method* and is executed automatically when the `controller` loads.

So, call playAnimation() from `changeAnimationButtonClicked()` instead.

```
@objc func changeAnimationButtonClicked() {
    playAnimation()
}
```

**2.** Also, in case you want a different animation everytime the button is pressed, there is no point in storing it in `var name`. Instead create a **computed property** and return `animations.randomElement()` from it.

```
var name: String? {
    return animations.randomElement()
}
```

So, here you go with the code,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let animations = ["sports-loader", "loader", "lottie", "mail", "tick-bounce-1", "tick-bounce-2"]
    var name: String? {
        return animations.randomElement()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        makeButton()
    }

    func makeButton() {
        //rest of the code...
    }

    private func playAnimation() {
        if let name = self.name {
            //rest of the code...
        }
    }

    @objc func changeAnimationButtonClicked() {
        playAnimation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`randomElement()` is a function.

Also you must set `lazy var` otherwise you will have an error

Try this `lazy var name: String? = animations.randomElement()`